# Multiple applications from the same Codeigniter code base

Tags: php, codeigniter

My product has 70 customers. Each customer has a MYSQL database and I am using Codeigniter.

I have 70 subfolders e.g domain.com/customer1/ domain.com/customer2/ and so on and in each of these folders, I have mentioned the database details of the specific customer, along with all the files for codeigniter installation.

I want to get rid of all these installations and want to have only one installation for all my customers. Ideally domain.com/app/

What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried dynamically writing into the database.php file when one of the client logs in. So what I did is write the database details of the client in the database.php file of the one code base e.g domain.com/app/ and see if it worked. But it won't work for other clients, I think I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: You are maintaining a separate database for _each_ customer? Wow. Good luck maintaining that!

Comment: This is a complete disaster. The answer is simple, rewrite the application. But first take a few courses on Application design and Database design. Or employ someone who has a clue

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-make-multiple-websitesubdomain-of-your-main-site-in-codeigniter-with-same-code-and-database-dynamically/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a subdomain for each client and point the web root to that one folder. You can use the subdomain as the database name.

VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName client.domain.com 
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/clients/public_html 
        <Directory /home/clients/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then modify database.php like this

```
$client_name = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => "$client_name",
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'phppos_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, but it will not solve my problem of maintaining each subdomain for a client. Each subdomain will again create another folder in my server, which I don't want.

Comment: Right, thats an improvement over the original disaster

Comment: You don't need a folder for each subdomain. Just make a wildcard VHOST and point it to one folder. I have updated my answer with an example